# Oracle string declare error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I haven't used Oracle in quite some time. Simple question here.

I am using the following variable declaration and query:

```
declare
new_line := 'LINE_12';
begin
select dept from departments where line = new_line;
```

I am getting this error:

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 11: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" 
when expecting one of the following: constant exception 
<an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> 
table long double ref char time timestamp interval date 
binary national character nchar The symbol "<an identifier>" 
was substituted for "=" to continue.
```

Comment: When you declare a new variable (like `new_line` in your snippet), you must state its data type first, before you can assign to it. In your case: `new_line varchar2(30) := 'LINE_12'`. Or some other `varchar2` length (instead of 30) that will be sufficient to hold the initial value as well as any other values you may assign to the variable in your code.

Comment: Like this: new_line varchar(9) := 'LINE_12';  - something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not declared the datatype of the new_line, please assign datatype as VARCHAR2(size)

new_line varchar2(50) DEFAULT := 'LINE_12';
or
new_line varchar2(50) ;
assign value according to your convenience.

And make sure that the value  you pass is present in department table else it will return NULL.

Comment: Thank you, sir.  I received a comment stating just about the same thing you said.  If he does not post an answer, I will accept yours.